# For which $c\in\mathbb{R}$ $c>0$, exist such $g\in\mathbb{R}$, that $ g - \sqrt[g]{e}=c $

Tags: real-analysis

For which $c\in\mathbb{R}$ $c>0$, exist such $g\in\mathbb{R}$, that

$$ g - \mathrm e^{1/g}=c $$

It's a part of another task. If possible, please don't use derivatives, keep answer as simple as possible.

Comment: Plot $f(x) = x - \exp(1/x)$ and check where the line $y = c$ crosses it.

Comment: @Ilya I've done this in wolfram. It's like when c < 1.44 ($\sqrt[e]{e}$) But I don't know the formal proof

Comment: Come on, check $x\in (0,1)$ for negative $c$ and pay attention to the fact that $x - \exp(1/x) \to+\infty$ when $x\to +\infty$

Comment: @Jonny are you stating it is only true for $c=\sqrt[e]{e}$? That's not true.

Comment: $g\mapsto g-e^{1/g}$ is a continuous bijection $(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, one easily verifies that $f(x)  =x - \exp(1/x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. Note that 
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = -\infty, \quad \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = +\infty
$$
since in the first case $-\exp(1/x)$ dominates and in the second case $x$ is more important. By the intermediate value theorem we get that $f(x)$ takes all values in $\Bbb R$.